# Why is "-webkit-app-region" not a defined CSS property in most code editors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

This isn't something that affects the functionality of my app, but I've noticed that the "-webkit-app-region" CSS property (a Chromium window element property) isn't recognized in both Jetbrains Pycharm 2018.3.2 and VS 2017 Community edition. Does anyone know why this is? Every other Chromium property is recognized so I just found it odd that this one was the only exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PyCharm uses the **W3C CSS Validator**, the `-webkit-app-region` property is flagged as unknown because it's a non-standard CSS property.

Either way, you can easily add custom CSS props.

For **PyCharm 2018.3.2**:

- Go to **File** > **Settings**
- Navigate to **Editor** > **Inspections** > **Invalid elements**
- Click on **Unknown CSS property**, go to the options on the right bottom corner
- Add `-webkit-app-region` to the **Custom CSS properties** field

**VS 2017** has adaptive custom CSS properties, so no configuration required here!

Also, make sure you restart Pycharm for the changes to take effect! I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem in PyCharm, so I appreciate it! I probably should've looked a little harder for a solution, but I trust people here like you LOL